# Searching for a dialogue from one of the books from Belgariad or Mallorean

Tags: quotes, the-belgariad, david-eddings, the-malloreon

I don't have access to my books and have no PDF version of them, nor being able to find it using Google (seems I'm good at find anything with Google except from book quotes)

I'm searching for a dialogue from one of the books composing those saga: it's a dialogue between Durnik and another character I can't remember; they are talking about Mandorallen, who is in that moment charging some enemies while laughing out loudly, and (I think) Durnik is -disconsolatly- explaining that the reason is he tought Mandorallen to overcame his fears by laughing at them.

Is someone able to find and paste it?

Comment: Side note: I noticed we don't have a tag for the Mallorean books.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Magician's Gambit**

> Garion thought about Mandorallen's changed behavior as they rode on
>   down the valley. Back at the cave where the colt had been born, Durnik
>   had told Mandorallen that fear could be conquered by laughing at it,
>   and, though Durnik had probably not meant it in precisely that way,
>   Mandorallen had taken his words quite literally. The laughter which so
>   irritated Barak was not directed at the foes he met, but rather at the
>   enemy within him. Mandorallen was laughing at his own fear as he rode
>   to each attack.
>
> "It's unnatural," Barak was muttering to Silk. "That's what bothers me
>   so much. Not only that, it's a breach of etiquette. If we ever get
>   into a serious fight, it's going to be terribly embarrassing to have
>   him giggling and carrying on like that. What will people think?"
>
> "You're making too much of it, Barak," Silk told him. "Actually, I
>   think it's rather refreshing."

Comment: Darn it! Beat me to it.

Comment: Thanks, Richard, I'll accept the answer as soon as possible (one minute, it seems). As an added bonus (so to say), would you be willing to copy/paste the above mentioned dialogue between Durnik and Mandorallen? I think it will add something to the answer. Thx again :-)

Comment: @motoDrizzt - Alas, I don't have the full quote, just what you see on the page.

Comment: @Richard no probs, after all the above quote was exactly was I was asking for :-)

Answer (score 5):

Captured from https://books.google.nl/books?isbn=1407056603: (Magician's Gambit)[image]

> Ordinary men are afraid almost every minute of their lives."
>   "How can you bear it?"
>   "Do we have any choice? Fear's a part of life, Mandorallen, and it's the only 
>   life we have. You'll get used to it. After you've put it on every morning like 
>   an old tunic, you won't even notice it any more. Sometimes laughing at it helps 
>   - a little."
>   "Laughing?"
>   "It shows the fear that you know it's there, but that you're going to go ahead 
>   and do what you have to do anyway." Durnik looked down at his hands, carefully 
>   kneading the mare's belly. "Some men curse and swear and bluster," he continued.
>   "That does the same thing, I suppose. Every man has to come up with his own 
>   technique for dealing with it. Personally, I prefer laughing. It seems more 
>   appropriate somehow."
>   Mandorallen's face became gravely thoughtful as Durnik's words slowly sank in. 
>   "I will consider this," he said. "It may be, good friend, that I will owe thee 
>   more than my life for thy gentle instruction."